# Unexpected token export and a lot more errors on import of google charts in meteor js via npm

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, google-visualization, npm-install

I am trying to use google charts with meteor js.

I had it installed via NPM by:

```
meteor npm install --save google-charts
```

I'm just trying to do a simple example, but when I try to import google charts in meteor using this, **import { GoogleCharts } from 'google-charts';** the project gets messed up.

The first line in the stacktrace is:
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export** then the specific line it points to is. Not sure, but it doesn't recognized export?

```
export let GoogleCharts = new googleCharts();
```

Then after this, I get a lot more Uncaught TypeError

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'URL' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Base64' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'EJSON' of undefinedUncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Blaze' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Blaze' of undefined
```

and there's a lot more undefined errors.

This happens whenever I import google charts to the page I am working on.

This is the first time I tried to install a library via npm, usually I just use meteor install. Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Try the install multiple times. It seems npm has technical issues.

Comment: I did your advise on my windows pc and an ubuntu pc, but still get the errorsss

Comment: Did you try `npm cache clean --force`?

Comment: I fixed it. The error that I was not able to show here is that the export command is not recognized. I dunno why but there appears to be some differences with the export. so since the google-charts npm is in node modules, I modified the js file. instead of exporting via export I used module.exports = googleCharts.